# Use ifelse() to Identify inconsistent responses in data

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a long format dataframe of responses to a repeated question about puberty status `vb_` asked approximately yearly at ages 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, and 17.

Each year participants were asked to rate their development from 1 to 5, with 1 being least developed and 5 being most developed.

I would like to use R's `ifelse()` to identify inconsistent responses i.e. those that report a stage at one year that is lower than any of the previous years.

Here is some fake example data for 20 people:

```
vb <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
                        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
                        8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                        10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                        11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                        13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
                        15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
                        16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
                        18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
                        19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), age = c(9L, 10L, 
                                                                              11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
                                                                              17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 
                                                                              14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 
                                                                              10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
                                                                              16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
                                                                              13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
                                                                              9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 
                                                                              15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                              11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
                                                                              17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 
                                                                              14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 
                                                                              10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
                                                                              16L, 17L), vb_ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                                                                 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           -160L), .Names = c("id", "age", "vb_"))
```

Comment: Off topic: why is that inconsistent? :)

Comment: Because it doesn't make too much sense to go backwards in sexual development over time e.g. you can't really report having adult pubic hair at one age and the next year report that your pubic hair is not yet adult like

Comment: Depending on how the question is asked, the respondent may answer in relative terms. The respondent may consider being developed year t relatively speaking, but less developed year t + 1 if classmates had a rapid development during that specific year.

Comment: That is a very interesting point thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on a `ifelse` approach you can do:

```
vb <- vb[order(vb$id, vb$age), ]
vb$inconsistent <- ifelse(vb$id == lag(vb$id), 
                          ifelse(vb$vb_ < lag(vb$vb_), "inconsistent", ""), 
                          "")
vb$inconsistent[1] <-  ""

    id age vb_ inconsistent
1    1   9   1             
2    1  10   1             
3    1  11   1             
4    1  13   3             
5    1  14   4             
6    1  15   4             
7    1  16   4             
8    1  17   5             
9    2   9   2             
10   2  10   2             
11   2  11   3             
12   2  13   4             
13   2  14   5             
14   2  15   5             
15   2  16   5             
16   2  17   5             
17   3   9   2             
18   3  10   3             
19   3  11   3             
20   3  13   3             
21   3  14   4             
22   3  15   4             
23   3  16   4             
24   3  17   5             
25   4   9   2             
26   4  10   1 inconsistent
27   4  11   3             
...
```

Or one approach with `dplyr` is:

```
library(dplyr)

vb %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, age) %>% 
  mutate(vb_diff = vb_ - lag(vb_)) %>% 
  filter(vb_diff < 0)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [5]
     id   age   vb_ vb_diff
  <int> <int> <int>   <int>
1     4    10     1      -1
2     5    11     1      -1
3     5    15     3      -1
4     8    15     4      -1
5     9    11     1      -1
6    10    16     4      -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
vb <- vb[order(vb$id, vb$age),]

vb$decreasingdevelopment <- c(0, diff(vb$vb_))<0 #difference between this score and previous <0
vb$sameperson <- c(0, diff(vb$id))==0 #is this the same participant than previous

vb$inconsistency <- vb$decreasingdevelopment&vb$sameperson #ifelse(vb$devdiff&vb$sameperson, T, F)
which(vb$inconsistency)
#[1] 26 35 38 62 67 79
```

Note that the use of `ifelse()` is possible but not necessary.

PS: for completeness of the answer, you should always use the following :

```
vb$inconsistency_robust <- apply(vb, 1, function(x) length(which(vb$vb_>x["vb_"]&vb$age<x["age"]&vb$id==x["id"]))>0)
#x["decreasingdevelopment"]&x["sameperson"])
all.equal(which(vb$inconsistency_robust), which(vb$inconsistency))

#> which(vb$inconsistency_robust) 
#[1] 26 35 38 62 63 67 79
#> which(vb$inconsistency)
#[1] 26 35 38 62 67 79
```

Note how the robust method spots all the occurences of inconsistencies while my more naive `ifelse()` method here only compares line to line.